# Можно ли растянуть сайт на 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как растянуть сайт в CSS на 100%, чтобы пользователю не приходилось самостоятельно изменять расширение браузерa. Когда захожу на localhost приходится увеличивать масштаб до 110%, чтобы сайт корректно отображался. Width: 1440px, не особо хочется менять width , а вместе с ним все остальное.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Simon исправил вопрос, надеюсь суть вопроса понятна

Comment: То есть получается что-то вроде того что максимальная ширина контейнера 1440px, но Вам хотелось бы чтобы этот контейнер был 100% в ширину от экрана, верно? Ну тогда наверное не следовало бы задавть фиксированную ширину в пикселях или как Вы себе это сейчас себе видите?

Comment: @Simon я думал что можно растянуть сайт через CSS, сейчас понимаю что стоило использовать ширину в процентах